# add_option in multisite

Tags: wordpress

I want to add option, called `enable_image` in `wp_options` table in multisite. i.e each individual blog id. And I want to get the value of checkbox and save it in wp_options table.

```
<td><fieldset><legend class="screen-reader-text"><span><?php _e('Allow Contributor To   Upload') ?></span></legend>
<label for="enable_app1">

<input name="enable_app1" type="checkbox" id="enable_app1" value="1" <?php checked('1',  get_option('enable_image')); ?> />

<?php _e('Yes Allow Contributor To Upload.') ?></label><br />
</fieldset></td>
</tr>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to suggest a different way to approach this which I think is what you really want. First, save your value network-wide using [update_site_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_site_option).

```
update_site_option( 'enable_app1', $_POST['enable_app1'] );
```

Then, whenever you need to use this value you can retrieve it like this:

```
if( get_option( 'enable_app1' ) ) {
    $enable_app1 = get_option( 'enable_app1' );
}
else {
    $enable_app1 = get_site_option( 'enable_app1' );
}
```

Which says, if a value has been set for this blog particularly, use it. Otherwise, use the option that has been set network wide. This allows the administrator to override the options locally while saving him the work to explicitly set the value on each blog.

If you don't need to be able to override things locally, you could use `update_site_option` alone. It's preferable compared to setting the value on each blog and will have the same effect. But yet, if you want to do that, you can do it as well by first checking to see if the network wide option has been set and then update the local value to match it, using an action hook.

Comment: @brasofilo you are right, but past these days i was unable to accept any answer because i had only 1 reputation